# Getting data returned from a jquery ajax call

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to get the data return from a function called by a jquery ajax call. My function is located in a a php file and it looks liket his

```
valid_user() {

    $id = $_POST('id');

    if($id == 'hello'){
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

and here is my ajax call

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: path + "valid_user",
    sucess: function(msg) {
         alert("Data returned: " + msg );
     }
 });
```

I have tested everthing and the function is wokring ( has been changed for this example) but I can not the return value of the function valid_id(). How do I get this? the variable msg keeps coming back empty. Thanks

Comment: are you ever calling the valid_user() function in your php script. And if so are you echo(ing) out the result afterwards?

Answer (score 4):

From my understanding, there are several issues.

1) the method valid_user() is not been called.
2) The url doesn't look like it is correct either.
3) The "success" keyword is spelt "sucess".
4) You aren't passing any "data".

Here is an example ajax call tailored to what you may want.

```
 $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "validateUser.php",
   data: "id=49",
   success: function(msg){
     alert( "true or false: " + msg );
   }
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you misspelled `sucess`----but this may not be in your running code. You should check the *second* parameter of `success`:

```
success:function(data, textStatus)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to write PHP server-side code that calls the function and writes its return value to the output stream.  For example:

```
<?php echo valid_user(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work - you might want to put better sanitizing on the POST value just in case.

In the PHP file:

```
$id = isset($_POST['id']) ? trim($_POST['id']) : '';
$return = 'false';

if($id!=''){
   valid_user($id);
}

echo $return;

valid_user($id) {
    if($id == 'hello'){
        $return = 'true';
    }
}
```

jQuery Call:

```
<script>
id = 'hello';    
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "validateUser.php?id="+id,
   success: function(msg) {
      alert("Data returned: " + msg );
   }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help, I figured out the issue, the reason why it was not working was becuase my function valid_id() was returning true or false, and I needed to return echo "true"; and echo "false"; once I did this the msg variable contained the data true or false.